# Update text field in vue test utils (jest) not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

Hi i am new in jest and unit testing. i want to ask how to set value text input using vue test utils.

shortly I have custom component for text input, its my code

```
<input
    v-model="local_value"
    @keyup.enter="submitToParent"
    :class="input_class"
    :id="id"
    :disabled="is_disabled"
    :maxlength="max_length"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    :autocomplete="(is_autocomplete) ? 'on' : 'off'"
    :name="id"
    :ref="id"
  />
```

and it's my test

```
it("type something on field", async () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(TextInput, {
            propsData: {
                id: "my_input",
            }
        })

        // find component (its work properly) and I want to try inserting some text
        const input = wrapper.findComponent({ref: "my_input"})
        input.element.value = "sample text"
        input.setValue("sample text")

        // the value still empty string (""), idk what happens with my code
        console.log(wrapper.vm.local_value)
        expect(wrapper.vm.local_value).toBe("sample text")
```

please tell me if you known solution for this problem, thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `setValue` is async, so you might need to set it with
`await input.setValue('sample text')`

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting the vm's `local_value`  value, you'd want to set it as:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(TextInput)
await wrapper.setData({
   local_value: 'sample text'
})
```

.... if the `local_value` is declared in `data()`, or:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(TextInput)
await wrapper.setProps({
   local_value: 'sample text'
})
```

... if the `local_value` is declared in `props()` in your component.

Then check it with:

```
expect(wrapper.vm.local_value).toBe('sample text')
```

Although that's just the vm value and not rendered value on DOM.

If you'd like to check including the rendered value, you have to declare first the property `value` on your component for it to be testable:

```
<input
    v-model="local_value"
    // ... rest of the properties
    :value="local_value"
/>
```

and test it with:

```
const input = await wrapper.findComponent({ ref: "my_input" })
expect(input.attributes('value').toBe('sample text')
```

Ideally, your test will look like this:

```
it('should have input value' async () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(TextInput)
  await wrapper.setProps({  local_value: 'sample text' })
  
  const input = await wrapper.findComponent({ ref: 'my_input' })
  expect(wrapper.vm.local_value).toBe('sample text')
  expect(input.attributes('value').toBe('sample text')
})
```

Some tip:

You can check the rendered attributes input by commenting all `expect` and put:

```
expect(input.attributes('').toBe('random chars here to force an error')
```

Console will display the errors with the expected attributes output